# Adjusting uniform sampling by relative weights

Tags: sampling, importance-sampling

Assume a population of businesses, each given a size value which is proportional to their popularity. The sampling design is as follows, and cannot be changed:
1. Choose a random business uniformly, disregarding their size.
2. Obtain a sample from that business (let's assume a categorical value).

How should I adjust the sampled values to make them representative with respect to the business's popularity? Is it correct to just multiply the value by each business's size and then normalize by the total size of sampled businesses?

Comment: Do you know which samples (obtained in (2)) came from which business?

Comment: Can you define more precisely what kind of sample you take? How are you going to multiply a categorical variable?

Comment: In your second paragraph it's not clear what "value" you are referring too, since we assume the sample is categorical..

Comment: If you are allowed to intervene after step (1) you can add a rejection step before potentially accepting the sample from step (2)